# i is referred in both cases but it gives me an error when I write it differently

Tags: python

```
def censor(line):
return ''.join(i ='*' * len(i) if len(i) > 4 else i for i in line)
```

gives me error

```
def censor2 (your_word):
spl = your_word.split()
empty_list = []
for i in spl:
    if len(i) >= 4:
        i = '*' * len(i)
    empty_list.append(i)
return ' '.join(empty_list)
```

but this does not when I say i = '*' * len(i)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def censor(line):
    return ''.join('*' * len(i) if len(i) > 4 else i for i in line)
```

Assignments, like `i=`, are not allowed in the shortcut `if`-condition (also not needed here).